# Generating special secure id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to generate a unique reference in the format similar to ABC-4F-ABC-8D-ABC (where: ABC is random 3-char string, 4F, 8D are random hex numbers).
I am a new guy to ruby, so please forgive me if this is duplicate(did not found smth that is similar so far).  How can I do this?

Comment: Why this format? Perhaps a simple `SecureRandom.uuid` would be a better option?

Comment: It was mentioned in my task. I suppose I should build something like my own randomizer to build the parts and then add them together?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is premature. You need to try, then when you encounter ask a detailed question about the problem. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. Once you've hit a problem with your code read "[mcve]". "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" will also explain our expectations when you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need is built into Ruby.

You can create an array that is your alphabet and then pick `sample`s from it to form your string:

```
ALPHA = ('A'..'Z').to_a # might also want to add numbers or lower-case letters?
HEX = ('A'..'F').to_a + (0..9).to_a

def generate_string(alphabet, length)
  # pick random elements from the alphabet and concatenate 
  # until length is reached.
  # key method is `sample` which selects a random element from 
  # an array (the alphabet, in your case)
  # you can try it on irb like so:
  # [1, 2, 3].sample
end
```

Then you can do something like:

```
def generate_unique_reference
  "#{generate_string(ALPHA, 3)}-#{generate_string(HEX, 2)}-....."
end
```

I'll leave it to you to complete the exercise (sounds like homework, no?)